# 'Use of class template requires template arguments' error with default specified non-type template parameter value

Tags: c++, templates

Compiling this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <auto val = 42>
struct A
{
    A()
    {
        std::cerr << val << "\n";
    }
};


int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr {new A {}};

    return 0;
}
```

gives `error: use of class template 'A' requires template arguments`. Although I provide a default value for non-type template parameter and expect it to be seen and used by compiler somehow. What do I miss here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it works fine with A<>, but I thought there is some way around A<>.

Comment: You can use A() :D. Jokes aside, you won't get around this for pure type inference (i.e. without an instance). That's why `A a;` will be fine, but `std::shared_ptr<A<>> ptr;` requires more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's still a template, and it still requires `<` and `>`:

```
std::shared_ptr<A<>> a_ptr {new A<> {}};
```

Think about this. If you have a function with a default parameter:

```
int foo(int baz=42);
```

Do you think you can simply call it without the parentheses?

```
int bar=foo;
```

Of course not, this won't work. You still need the parentheses:

```
int bar=foo();
```

Same thing with templates.

Comment: Huh, I've used templates for years and never made the mental connection between function call syntax with default arguments and template instantiation with default arguments. This is a good answer

Comment: "Do you think you simply call it witout the parenthesis? ...Of course not..." Except that sometimes you can use templates without  `<>`, so the "Of course not" is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

`A` doesn't name a `class`, it names a class template.

You need to use `A<>` to name the instantiation of the template that uses the default value:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<A<>> a_ptr {new A<> {}};
//              ^~~ here and    ^~~ here
```

If you are in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) or above, as is implied by the `auto` template parameter, you may remove the `<>` from `A`'s *construction* since this qualifies as CTAD, but it's still needed in the type for `shared_ptr`

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<A<>> a_ptr {new A {}};
//              ^~~ only here
```

**Note:** This only applies if there is no ambiguity to the type. If a constructor qualifies for CTAD, this will deduce a (possibly different) type than `A<>`

For example, if `A` were defined as:

```cpp
template <typename T = int>
struct A
{
    A(){}
    A(T x){}
};
```

Then:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<A<>> a_ptr {new A {}};
```

would succeed, but

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<A<>> a_ptr {new A {0.1}};
```

would fail, since `new A {0.1}` deduces `A<double>`, but `A<>` names `A<int>`

Comment: looks like there is should be another A<>, like `std::shared_ptr<A<>> a_ptr {new A<> {}};`

Comment: @Human-Compiler : I believe you need the `A<>` in the shared_ptr, not the new.

Comment: Whoops, thanks for the catch -- tried typing that quickly and was still the second answer. I've added some additional notes to indicate this. Also `A {}` only works since it qualifies for CTAD, but in more complex expressions can produce an ambiguity that is different from `A<>`